# Cauchy condesation theorem exercise like

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Pleas, give a hint with this exercise.

If $(a^k)$ is a non increasing sequence with $a_k\to 0$. Is it true that

The series $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ is convergent iff the series $\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}2^{2^{k}}a_{2^{2^{k}}}$ is convergent?
I am trying, to find an inequality,to use comparison and Cauchy condensation theorem, but i get nothing.

Thank you

Comment: $(a^k)$ or $(a_k)$? $2^{2^k}$ or $2^{k}$ ?

Comment: $(a_k)$ should be sequence of strictly positive numbers as well!

Comment: (1) Perhaps you should lower that index from $\;a^k\;$ to $\;a_k\;$ ...? (2) If the sequence is non-increasing and $\;a_k\to0\;$ then it must be a **positive** sequence so you can directly use the condensation test...

Comment: It seems like there's probably a typo in the general term's index: shouldn't it be $\;a_{2^n}\;$ instead of $\;a_{2^{2^n}}\;$ ? And please do address the comments .

Answer (score 1):

By the Cauchy condensation test
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n
$$
converges if and only if
$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty 2^ka_{2^k}
$$
converges. Applying the test again, this is equivalent to the convergence of 
$$
\sum_{j=1}^\infty 2^j\,2^{2^j}a_{2^{2^j}}=\sum_{j=1}^\infty 2^{2^j+j}a_{2^{2^j}}
$$
Now use $0<j<2^j$ to conclude for the claim.